# Run more than one thread in micropython(pico w)

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

i am gettinig this error below when i try to run the second thread on my pico w.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 114, in <module>
OSError: core1 in use
```

I am trying to display some content in one thread, and in another, server a simple web page with the same content.

```py
"""BME688 / BME680 demo
This demo will work for both the BME680 and BME688.
"""
print("lets import and use the libraries")

import time
from time import sleep
import network
import socket
import _thread
from breakout_bme68x import BreakoutBME68X, STATUS_HEATER_STABLE
from pimoroni_i2c import PimoroniI2C

from picographics import PicoGraphics, DISPLAY_LCD_240X240, PEN_P8

display = PicoGraphics(display=DISPLAY_LCD_240X240, pen_type=PEN_P8)
display.set_backlight(1.0)

WIDTH, HEIGHT = display.get_bounds()

ssid = 'netgear_2.4g' #Your network name
password = '9xc4prce' #Your WiFi password

print("setting pin breakouts etc")

PINS_BREAKOUT_GARDEN = {"sda": 4, "scl": 5}
PINS_PICO_EXPLORER = {"sda": 20, "scl": 21}

print("finish setting pins and now set i2c")

i2c = PimoroniI2C(**PINS_BREAKOUT_GARDEN)

print("i2c set and now set bme")

bme = BreakoutBME68X(i2c)

print("bme set")
# If this gives an error, try the alternative address
# bme = BreakoutBME68X(i2c, 0x77)

temperatureReadingData = ["","0.0c"]

print("Testing sensors on the while loop")

def connect():
    #Connect to WLAN
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)
    while wlan.isconnected() == False:
        print('Waiting for connection...')
        sleep(1)
    ip = wlan.ifconfig()[0]
    print(f'Connected on {ip}')
    return ip

def open_socket(ip):
    # Open a socket
    address = (ip, 80)
    connection = socket.socket()
    connection.bind(address)
    connection.listen(1)
    return connection

def readTemperature():
    temperature, pressure, humidity, gas, status, _, _ = bme.read()
    heater = "Stable" if status & STATUS_HEATER_STABLE else "Unstable"
    temperatureReadingData[0] = "Temperature is {:0.2f}c, Pressure is {:0.2f}Pa, humidity is {:0.2f}%, gas is {:0.2f} Ohms, Heater: {}".format(temperature, pressure, humidity, gas, heater)
    temperatureReadingData[1] = "{:0.2f}c".format(temperature)

def webpage(reading):
    #Template HTML
    html = f"""
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Pico W Weather Station</title>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
            </head>
            <body>
            <p>{reading}</p>
            </body>
            </html>
            """
    return str(html)

def serve():
    #Start a web server
    ip = connect()
    connection = open_socket(ip)
    while True:
        client = connection.accept()[0]
        request = client.recv(1024)
        request = str(request)       
        html = webpage(temperatureReadingData[0])
        client.send(html)
        client.close()
        
        
def displayTemp():
    while True:
        readTemperature()
        print("display temp" + temperatureReadingData[1])
        display.clear()
        display.set_pen(15)
        display.text(temperatureReadingData[1], 0, 0, scale=4)
        display.update()
        time.sleep(1.0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        tempDisplay = _thread.start_new_thread(displayTemp, ())
        webServer = _thread.start_new_thread(serve, ())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        machine.reset()
```

Comment: It might be more convenient to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if the threading issue doesn't go away w/o the hardware-specific code.

Comment: IIRC the main thread is already on core 0, e.g., you really only need to start up one thread (either one) and run the other at the root level so you really only need to start one new thread. Unrelated, but is the `__main__` part necessary? I don't recall having done that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than two threads in MicroPython (one per core) running at once on the RP2040.

You're trying to start two threads while still having a main thread, which if it worked would result in three threads.

To fix this, you can instead run either your displayTemp or serve functions in the main thread.

i.e:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        tempDisplayThread = _thread.start_new_thread(displayTemp, ())
        serve() # doesn't return

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        machine.reset()
```